# UIImage imageNamed

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to use a url as a `UIImage` in the OpenFlow API.

```
NSString *imageUrl = [[[newsEntries objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"still"] retain];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
UIImage *imageUI = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData]
UIImageView *myImage = [UIImageView initWithFrame:imageUI];
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myImage]];
[imageUr release];

[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:3];
```

I have tried it like this, but no success. The only way I got this API working was using the `imageNamed` type. The `initwithData` has no success.

So how can I change this `NSString` to finally become a `imageNamed` method?

Answer (score 2):

A UIImageView is different from a UIImage.

Change this line: `[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myImage]];`

To this: `[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageUI]];`

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have several significant errors here.  It appears that you may need to read about C/Objective-C and types.

It sounds like you are asserting that, specifically, the line

```
UIImage *imageUI = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData]
```

is not working. The code up to that point actually looks okay (though it is not necessary to retain and then release the `imageUrl` variable.

Once you have created your `UIImage`, you should be able to pass it directly to your `AFOpenFlowView`:

```
[(AFOpenFlowView*)self.view setImage:imageUI forIndex:0];
```

The line

```
UIImageView *myImage = [UIImageView initWithFrame:imageUI];
```

has two errors (and is unnecessary anyway). First, `-initWithFrame` takes a `CGRect` as its argument, not a `UIImage`.  `UIImageView` does have an initialization method `-initWithImage`, which is probably what you intended.  But either way, methods that start with "init" are instance methods, not class methods, so you have to call them on actual instances of a `UIImageView`, like this:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageUI];
```

Note that this will leak memory unless you autorelease or release it.

The following line, you correctly try to give a `UIImage` to your `AFOpenFlowView`, but you attempt to create that `UIImage` by passing a `UIImageView` to the `+imageNamed` method.  `+imageNamed` takes an NSString that contains the name of the image, and passing anything else to it won't work.

You must always be aware of what kind of object a method is expecting to receive, and make sure you find some way to give it that kind of thing.

Probably what you are looking for here is something like this:

```
NSString *imageUrl = [[newsEntries objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"still"];
NSString *imageName = [imageUrl lastPathComponent];
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```